# Hilti TE2 locked without bit

Tags: drill-bit, chuck

I’ve got a Hilti TE2 and am unable to put the bit in. I think I might have accidentally locked the chuck without a bit in it and now unable to unlock it to put the bit in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you pulling the chuck collar back towards the handle when trying to insert the bit?

Comment: Even without pulling back on the collar, I will insert the bit until it stops. Then I grasp the bit and rotate it until the bit grooves line up with the chuck bumps. Then the bit pops down and locks into place. Be sure to use a tiny bit of Hilti grease once in a while. On ebay I have seen used Hilti rotary hammers for sale. The picture shows a well-worn drill and an unused container of Hilti grease.